# Why I see ntdll disassembly, not my assembly code in WinDbg?

Tags: debugging, assembly, 64-bit, windbg, masm

I want to analyze my first assembler program. Look at registers, execute step by step etc. It's for learning purposes.

I have a problem. Disassembly is strange. I can't find my code. I step through some ntdll functions. There is no my MessageBoxA, no ExitProcess etc.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8hlMoG3.jpg]

I have used OllyDbg (32-bit) before and OllyDbg starts executing from normal entry of the program. Disassembly in OllyDbg was very similar to my MASM code.

What I am doing wrong? Why there is different disassembly? How to step through my code, not ntdll?

Comment: I guess OllyDbg knows its way around your import table so it can map the addresses to API calls - not the case with WinDbg. As long as you don't provide the symbols (.pdb files) it relies on exported names and maps the addresses relative to that. That's what you're seeing with `ntdll!memset` being the closest known to debugger symbol used to map addresses of call instructions to symbols.

Answer (score 2):

ollydbg interpreted the Address of Entry Point in the Pe Header and set a temporary BreakPoint and continued execution until that address Which Normally would be main if it was an assembler program or WinMainCrtStartup if it was compiler generated binary

Windbg will not do that it will stop at the system BreakPoint ( the default behavior of the Debug Apis)

you have two options

if it is your own assembler program and you have symbols for it 
do

```
.reload /f      
bp [your exe]![Your EntryPoint]     
bl to confirm if it is right     
g to continue execution and break in your code
```

if it is a third party program for which you do not have source

```
lmm [name of third party binary]    
!dh [start address of the third party binary]  ( see lm results  to know the address)     
look for Address of Entry Point     

 bp [start address of the third party binary] + [Address of entrypoint]
 g
```

windbg will stop in the user code

a sample for method 2 on calc.exe under win7 sp1

```
0:000> lm m calc
start    end        module name
00210000 002d0000   calc       (deferred)             
0:000> !dh 210000
---------------------
12D6C address of entry point

0:000> bp  210000+12d6c

0:000> bl
0 e 00222d6c     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!WinMainCRTStartup
0:000> g

calc!WinMainCRTStartup:
00222d6c e84bfdffff      call    calc!__security_init_cookie (00222abc)
```

Comment: Instead of fiddling around with `!dh` you can simply use the `$exentry` pseudo-register that contains the PE entry point of the main module. See my answer for this and other notes.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `bu $exentry; g`

---

Long answer:

A process starts its user mode execution in OS code found in `ntdll` which does all sorts of initialization and finally calls the entry point stored in the PE header.

WinDbg breaks in what's called the initial breakpoint (or ibp in WinDbg parlance). OllyDbg continues running after this breakpoint and sets a breakpoint on the PE entry point. That's nice, except when it screws you. For example, a well-known anti-debugging trick against olly was creating a binary with custom TLS callbacks, a rather esoteric feature. These callbacks are called **before** the PE entry point and thus go undetected by olly.

What you want to do is indeed set a breakpoint on the PE entry point.

The hard way is doing it like blabb did - using `!dh` to dump the module header and setting a breakpoint on the address noted there. Even the hard way can be a little easier, as there's no need to `lm` before running `!dh`. In WinDbg module names are interpreted at their base addresses. For example:

```
0:000> !dh -f notepad

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
FILE HEADER VALUES
     14C machine (i386)
       5 number of sections
55BEBE90 time date stamp Sun Aug 02 18:06:24 2015

       ...

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
     10B magic #
   12.10 linker version
   15400 size of code
   1F000 size of initialized data
       0 size of uninitialized data
   159F0 address of entry point
    1000 base of code
```

And then it's simply a matter of:

```
0:000> bu notepad+159F0
0:000> bl
 0 e 002259f0     0001 (0001)  0:**** notepad!WinMainCRTStartup
```

But the easy way is to use one of WinDbg's builtin [pseudo-registers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553485(v=vs.85).aspx) ("*automatic pseudo-registers*" is their term, in contrast to *user-defined pseudo-registers*), namely the aformentioned `$exentry`.

```
0:000> ? notepad + 159F0 == $exentry
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
0:000> ? $exentry
Evaluate expression: 2251248 = 002259f0
```

You can see that `002259f0` is the same address as the one we calculated by hand.

For completeness I note that there's the `$iment(`*`address`*`)` operator that gives the entry point of any module, not just the main module (the EXE):

```
0:000> ? $iment(winspool)
Evaluate expression: 1889096272 = 70995250
0:000> ln $iment(winspool)
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint

(70995250)   WINSPOOL!_DllMainCRTStartup   |  (7099526b)   WINSPOOL!__CppXcptFilter
Exact matches:
    WINSPOOL!_DllMainCRTStartup (<no parameter info>)
```